# iOS target deletes Watch App (but doesn't reinstall it)

Tags: watchkit, watch, xpc

Whenever I launch my iOS/iPhone Target the app is removed from the Watch.

Also of interest: When the watch app is deployed from Xcode, it quits with `signal 9`, something with XPC

Comment: There's something obviously wrong with your watch app.  I'm assuming Xcode will install it but your app won't.  I'd check things like code signing, version strings (note there are version strings in the iOS app, the app extension and the watch app).

Comment: @OwenHartnett thanks. Will check your ideas in January since I'm on holiday since today.